# I need to embedded skype window to my website

Tags: php, sdk, skype, skype-for-business

- I need to create a chat php application with Skype.
- As I cross the internet I could not find a way to embedded skype anywhere.
- Last thing I get is 2015 there were sdk for web but now its no where to find and with Microsoft involve, I'm confuse.
- Can anyone tell me about any detail about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information on how to develop applications that interact or embed skype [is overviewed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypedeveloperplatform). It sounds like you are looking for [a general reference on their web sdk](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Skype/WebSDK/docs/generalreference).

[Microsoft bought Skype](https://www.wired.com/2011/05/microsoft-buys-skype-2/) in 2011, which is why Microsoft is involved.

Comment: Thank you @Kris I have found all the information that I wants.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft bought Skype and also, things changed a bit. There is no way to use a SDK now to build what you need. You can however send them to the Skype for Web Skype version and people can use it without having an account if they don't want to. They have to visit Skype website, though and click on "Meet now", then start a conversation just picking up a name. It probably is far from what you expected so for the time being, another solution would be better.